# How might a site like Stack Overflow pass user information around in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-controls, openid

Basically, I log into my website using OpenId, very similar to what I am assuming SO does.  When I get the information back, I throw it into a database and create my "Registered User".  I set my AuthCookie:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Profile.MyProfile.DisplayName, false);
```

Then I can use this for the User Name.  However, I would like to pass in the entire object instead of just the string for display name.  So my question is:

How does SO do it?

Do they extend/override the `SetAuthCookie(string, bool)` method to accept the User object, i.e. `SetAuthCookie(User(object), bool)`.

What is the best way to persist a User object so that it is available to my UserControl on every single page of my Web Application?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you using to log in with OpenID? I've used http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid/ in the past with some success - I'm sure it provides samples that demonstrate what you want to do here.

Comment: I am using their ASP.NET MVC example to log in.  Just the core, then pick up in their method in the case statement (tis where I gor the line above.  Originally that code looked like this... FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(response.ClaimedIdentifier, false);  I just replaced the string with my users display name.  I want to be able to push some basic information with it, like they do here where they let you know your score, your userId (is in the hyperlink, etc.

Comment: Jeff!  DON'T USE DISPLAYNAME FOR YOUR USERNAME!  Sorry, but this is a HUGE security hole.  You MUST use the ClaimedIdentifier for the first parameter to SetAuthCookie.  Yes, this means controls like LoginName won't produce the results you want, but a tiny bit of convenience on your part isn't worth sacrificing that much security.

Comment: Yeah, I use ClaimedIdentifier now.  Really, it is all about the fastest and most secure way to pass around the entire user object when they are signed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this behavior by [implementing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) your custom [Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx), or extending an existing one. The provider stores user information based on a key (or just by user name) and provides access to the [MembershipUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx) class, which you can extend however you wish. So when you call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(...)`, you basically set the user key, which can be accessed be the provider.

When you call `Membership.GetUser()`, the membership infrastructure will invoke the underlying provider and call its `GetUser(...)` method providing it with a key of the current user. Thus you will receive the current user object.

Answer (score 2):

Jeff,

As I said in a comment to your question above, you *must* use the ClaimedIdentifier for the username -- that is, the first parameter to SetAuthCookie.  There is a huge security reason for this.  Feel free to start a thread on dotnetopenid@googlegroups.com if you'd like to understand more about the reasons.

Now regarding your question about an entire user object... if you wanted to send that down as a cookie, you'd have to serialize your user object as a string, then you'd HAVE TO sign it in some way to protect against user tampering.  You might also want to encrypt it.  Blah blah, it's a lot of work, and you'd end up with a large cookie going back and forth with every web request which you don't want.

What I do on my apps to solve the problem you state is add a static property to my Global.asax.cs file called CurrentUser.  Like this:

```
public static User CurrentUser {
    get {
        User user = HttpContext.Current.Items["CurrentUser"] as User;
        if (user == null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            user = Database.LookupUserByClaimedIdentifier(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
            HttpContext.Current.Items["CurrentUser"] = user;
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

Notice I cache the result in the HttpContext.Current.Items dictionary, which is specific to a single HTTP request, and keeps the user fetch down to a single hit -- and only fetches it the first time if a page actually wants the CurrentUser information.

So a page can easily get current logged in user information like this:

```
User user = Global.CurrentUser;
if (user != null) { // unnecessary check if this is a page that users must be authenticated to access
    int age = user.Age; // whatever you need here
}
```

Comment: I am going to look into this.  I spent 8 hours yesterday making my own MembershipProvider.  In a few hours I will update.  This way is much easier than the way I did it yesterday.  I also like what I see here.

Comment: I think that this is what I am going to go with.  It plugs right in to what I have and only requires the one call like you mention. I very well could do this without the custom provider at all using the method you described.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad it will work for you.  I find that the asp.net membership provider is a very poor fit for redirect-based, passwordless authentication protocols such as OpenID.  Any membership provider that works with OpenID can only be implemented half-way and hokey at best due to the interface that just doesn't fit very well.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to inject into your controller a class that is responsible for retrieving information for the current logged in user.  Here is how I did it.  I created a class called WebUserSession which implements an interface called IUserSession.  Then I just use dependency injection to inject it into the controller when the controller instance is created.  I implemented a method on my interface called, GetCurrentUser which will return a User object that I can then use in my actions if needed, by passing it to the view.

```
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web;

public interface IUserSession
{
    User GetCurrentUser();
}

public class WebUserSession : IUserSession
{
    public User GetCurrentUser()
    {
        IIdentity identity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
        if (!identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return null;
        }

        User currentUser = // logic to grab user by identity.Name;
        return currentUser;
    }
}

public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserSession _userSession;

    public SomeController(IUserSession userSession)
    {
        _userSession = userSession;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        User user = _userSession.GetCurrentUser();
        return View(user);
    }
}
```

As you can see, you will now have access to retrieve the user if needed.  Of course you can change the GetCurrentUser method to first look into the session or some other means if you want to, so you're not going to the database all the time.